# Can not connect with AWS : Connection time out error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using ssh command to connect with AWS instance :

`ssh -i ./abcd.pem ubuntu@ec2-**-***-**-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

These are my inbound rules :

[image]

Earlier It was working well suddenly it started giving this error I have also tried with different networks still the same problem.

Comment: if you have rebooted your ec2 instance then your ip should be changed. therefore double check the public ip and use it to ssh or it is better if you can create an elastic ip for your ec2.

Comment: Are you sure your IP address (added to the security group) hasn't changed?

Comment: Yeah! I have checked in the browser that myip is the same which I have entered in the inbound rules.

Comment: @HimanshuTeotia did you manage to resolve the issue after? If one of the answers didn't cover what the solution turned out to be, please consider adding your own answer. :-)

Comment: @entpnerd Thanks for asking...I have still not got any solution of this problem yet.

Comment: did you try suggestions in my answer yet?

Comment: Yeah! I tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that AWS hasn't stopped you from connecting because you're out of money, the simplest explanation is that your host is simply unstable and [needs to be rebooted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html).

Comment: I just rebooted my AWS instance and still, it is not connecting :(

Comment: Is it a payment problem per chance?

Comment: I am using free version of t2.micro for one year and it's been a few months since. Is there any way to find out whether this is a payment issue?

Comment: Launch time - January 31, 2018 at 3:47:35 PM UTC+8 (4341 hours)

Comment: Did your IP change? Also, try this page on performing status checks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Comment: Also, a stupid question: Is your `abcd.pem` file actually in the current directory when you run the `ssh` command?

Comment: Its Okay, - Yes, It is I am using tab for that (y)

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps there is an issue with your inbound rules. From the host where you want to execute your SSH command, follow this page on setting up access rules to your host: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Pay special attention to __"To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic over IPv4 using the console"__ and on #4 it states "__In the Source field, choose My IP to automatically populate the field...__".

Comment: Edited the comment.

Comment: One more thing to try. This AWS doc page has pretty precise troubleshooting steps on connecting to your AWS resources. It also has the error message in the question: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Stop your instance and start again, try to connect by new IP address, if still not works, you have the Internet connection problem.